# Undefined class made by scaffold rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I find this problem while following the tutorial using scaffold

```
undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass
```

I have no idea why this is happening, since I didn't change anything and this methods is automatically written by the scaffold when I generate the Comment class. What's happening? I'm amateur, so I don't know what code to show here.
Thank you very much for your help.

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @link = Link.find(params[:link_id])
    @comment = @link.comments.new[comment_params]
    @comment.try[:user] = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:link_id, :body, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the remaining code for that code snippet?

Comment: I have updated the code snippet @Pavan

Comment: Try `@comment = @link.comments.new(comment_params)` instead of `@comment = @link.comments.new[comment_params]`

Comment: thanks! I think this is the one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass

I believe the error is due to the below line

```
@comment = @link.comments.new[comment_params]
```

which should be

```
@comment = @link.comments.new(comment_params)
```